# chunk, ext4 stride and strip-width size for RAID level 1?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, raid-1

the man page for `mdadm` says: "[chunk] is  only  meaningful  for RAID0, RAID4, RAID5, RAID6, and RAID10." i.e. it does not apply for raid1. even if you pass the value, it will say `ignoring chunk size` and after the raid 1 is created, you get:

```
md1 : active raid1 ...
      4883639488 blocks super 1.2 ...
      bitmap: 0/37 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

For some reason it used a 65Mb for a 5.6Tb disk size. Why?

Then, the man page for `mkfs.ext4` says

> stride=stride-size  = Configure  the  filesystem  for  a RAID array
> with stride-size filesystem blocks. This is the number of blocks read
> or written to   disk before moving to the next disk, which is
> sometimes referred to as the chunk size.  This mostly affects
> placement of filesystem metadata like bitmaps at mke2fs time to
> avoid placing them on a single disk, which can hurt performance.  It
> may also be used   by the block allocator.
>
> stripe_width=stripe-width =  Configure the filesystem for a RAID array
> with stripe-width filesystem blocks per stripe. This  is  typically
> stride-size  *  N,   where  N  is  the  number of data-bearing disks
> in the RAID (e.g. for RAID 5 there is one parity disk, so N will be
> the number of   disks in the array minus 1).  This allows the block
> allocator to prevent read-modify-write of the parity in a RAID stripe
> if possible when the data is written.

What does all that means for RAID1? should I just repeat the same value as i got for chunk above? and ignore stripe_width as RAID1 falls out of the "if possible" note? or does it not?

It's not very clear what I am supposed to do for RAID1. using the formulas i found in other tutorials for RAID0 and RAID5, i got those numbers for my RAID1 array, which i think are NOT correct.. `mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 -E stride=16384,stripe-width=16384`

Answer (score 1):

I think this sould be fine as you are not striping anything. You only need that number to tell after how much data the next disk should be used. However, you effectively have only one data disk (and one mirror of it) so the controller doesn't need to change the disk and thus it should be fine. The high number also makes sense in my opinion as the controller would only ask itself after a large chunk which disk to use. So this should limit the overhead.

Comment: what about the stripe part? i still have two+ disks as `data-bearing` to use the man page terms.

Answer (score 1):

RAID1 is effectively the same as a single disk so there is no RAID optimisation to be had, but there are still ways of optimising your file system metadata locations based on your application's I/O profile and possibly the underlying disk's abilities (e.g. SSD erase block size). I wrote an article on this exact subject a while back, explaining why [file system alignment](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/08/18/mysql-mariadb-innodb-on-non-zfs/) matters, which you may find useful.

Comment: excellent article! one question... you mention `stripe-width=`  is only taking one disk into account while the manual I quote above says `blocks * data-bearing disks`. Why did you chose N=1 if your raid0 all disks hold data?

Comment: @gcb because we want the file system to treat each of the two disks as self contained. We don't want a data update on one to trigger a metadate on the other and waste an iop from each instead of just one. This was a specific RAID0 edge case used to illustrate the point, in reality we would never use RAID0 in production.

Comment: I see. So, if i value consistency, should I use N=total disks, for my raid1?

Comment: No, for raid1 n should be 1, same as a single disk.